# Script to change wallpaper in windows 10 not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, script, desktop-customization

I am trying to get a script to work that will change the default wallpaper for windows 10 because I will be deploying Win10 to all clients. When I run the batch code below, it is not changing the default wall paper. I see that the img0 file is in the correct directory C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows but it is not changing the background. The code below is what I am using. I do get some access denied errors when trying to del C:\Windows\Web\4K\Wallpaper\Windows\img0_1366x768.jpg
Access is denied.

```
takeown /f c:\windows\WEB\wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg
takeown /f C:\Windows\Web\4K\Wallpaper\Windows\*.*
icacls c:\windows\WEB\wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg /Grant System:(F)
icacls C:\Windows\Web\4K\Wallpaper\Windows\*.* /Grant System:(F)
del c:\windows\WEB\wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg
del /q C:\Windows\Web\4K\Wallpaper\Windows\*.*
copy %~dp0img0.jpg c:\windows\WEB\wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg
copy %~dp04k\*.* C:\Windows\Web\4K\Wallpaper\Windows
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? TIA

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ReplaceWallpaper>(
Takeown.exe /F "C:\WINDOWS\Web\" /R /D S
 Icacls.exe "C:\WINDOWS\Web\" /Grant "Administrator":"F" /T
 Del /Q "C:\WINDOWS\Web\wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg"


    Copy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ReplaceWallpaper\img0.jpg" "C:\WINDOWS\Web\wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg"
     REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V "Wallpaper" /T "REG_SZ" /D "C:\WINDOWS\Web\wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg" /F
    ) 1>Nul
    ERROR: File or Directory not found.
    C:\WINDOWS\Web" /Grant Administrator:F /T: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: Did you try rebooting after changing the image file like this?  My expectation would be that the file is read and loaded in to memory to be displayed as the background, changing the file directly (and doing nothing else) won't make the loaded copy change.

Comment: Thanks I just rebooted but unfortunately no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username you set in the `Icacls` command is wrong, you should be running as Admin, preferablly using the hidden **[Built-in Administrator Account](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/?PageSpeed=noscript)** if you get user-access denied, and use your username.

Secondlly, ensure to set the `Wallpaper` registry value of the current user, in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` registry key, that points to its current wallpaper.

Note that a logoff/restart is required under a limited language like Batch, which cannot notify about a system environment update.

Try this:

```
Set "oldWall=%WinDir%\Web\wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg"
Set "newWall=%~dp0img0.jpg"
Set "WallPath=%WinDir%\Web\Windows\"

(
Takeown.exe /F "%WallPath%" /R /D S
Icacls.exe "%WallPath%" /Grant "%username%":"F" /T
Del /Q "%oldWall%"
Copy "%newWall%" "%oldWall%"
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V "Wallpaper" /T "REG_SZ" /D "%oldWall%" /F
)1>Nul
```

But if your purpose is to deploy a Windows ISO with a custom wallpaper set, then the prefered solution is to use WSIM (**Windows System Image Manager**) , which is included in the WAIK (**Windows Automated Installation Kit**) or also known as WADK (**[Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721%28v=vs.8.5%29.aspx)**), this way you can generate an **AutoUnattend.xml** file that should ship inside the ISO together the setup.exe file, this way you can modify a variety of default values when installing Windows, such as the default wallpaper for all users.

Comment: Thank you this might be closer to what I need but I am getting an error. I added it above The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Below are fixes to what you provided above along with some recommendations.
At bottom solution to update wallpaper without a restart.

Error Produced:         "ERROR: File or Directory not found."
Error Producing Code:   Takeown.exe /F "C:\WINDOWS\Web\" /R /D S 
Fix:                    Takeown.exe /F "C:\WINDOWS\Web" /R /D Y

Explanation: /D has to be followed by Y for yes or N for No.
            Takeown has a bug and so no trailing backslash is allowed unless followed by a FileSpec/Wildcard token *

Non Error Producing Error: Administrator should be Administrators when adding Permissions with ICacls, unless you created a user name with the string 'Administrator', but follow what ElektroStudios stated above and use the current user.

Allowing the current user permissions to system files is not a good idea though because you are altering the security of your system. So your initial idea of allowing the administrators group permissions to these files is sound.

Scripting Style Error:
You shouldn't delete the wallpaper files because you can barely get this script to work. Until then you should just try to accomplish tasks thru your script without ruining files on the Operating System. This is just a good habit when it comes to scripting, so you don't ruin your computer or alter its security state. By changing the Wallpapers you could let a virus into your computer depending on where you get your wallpapers from.

Here is how to make the script work.
Taken from Rob Vanderwoude Script SetWallp.bat who credits Pete Smith for RUNDLL32 command to activate changes. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=setwallp_nt

Activate changes
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1 True

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing (in my experience) setting up `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop` more often would not work.

The best solution is to call win32 api function `SystemParametersInfoSetWallpaper` - it works every time. I found this powershell module/snippet to be quite helpful https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Change-window-borderdesktop-609a6fb2